# Copy dist to libs directory with web pack

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, webpack

I'd like to do the following:

Using gulp, I added this to my tasks:

```
gulp.task('copy:libs', function() {
  return gulp
    .src(npmdist(), { base: paths.base.node.dir })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist.libs.dir));
});
```

This copied my packages from `node_modules` to my libs directory. Now I'd like to do the same using webpack:

- Source: `node_modules/@fancyapps/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css`
- Target: `lib/css/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.min.css`

and

- Source: `node_modules/@fancyapps/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js`
- Target: `lib/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.min.js`

Unfortunately I did not find a possibility to do this using WebpackCopy, yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use copy-webpack-plugin to do this.

Run

```
npm i copy-webpack-plugin
```

Then in your webpack config file

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
      from: 'node_modules/something',
      to: 'somefolder',
    }]),
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the reference, if your using **Laravel Mix** you can use `mix.copy`.

for example

`mix.copy('node_modules/@fancyapps/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css', 'lib/css/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.min.css');`

or if you want to copy a directory

`mix.copyDirectory('node_modules/@fancyapps/fancybox/dist', 'lib/css/fancybox');`